# Numeros impares menor y mayor en una lista C++

Tags: c++

tengo que hacer un programa que muestre el numero menor y mayor de una lista, pero que estos sean impares
Hacer programa con listas simples o dobles para hallar el elemento impar menor y el elemento impar
mayor en una lista de números enteros.
Tengo este codigo, pero me da error
Me pueden ayudar por favor, soy nuevo

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

void main() {
    int n, x, mayor, menor, ci, cp, suma;
    float prom;
    char op;
    do {
        mayor = -1;
        menor = 10000;
        ci = 0;
        cp = 0;
        suma = 0;

        clrscr();

        do {
            cout << "Ingresar cantidad de numeros:";
            cin >> n;
        } while (n <= 0);

        for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
            do {
                cout << "Ingresar numero:";
                cin >> x;
            }

            while (x <= 0);
            if (x % 2 == 0)
                cp = cp + 1;
            else
                ci = ci + 1;
            if (x > mayor)
                mayor = x;
            if (x < menor)
                menor = x;
            suma = suma + x;
        }

        prom = suma / n;

        cout << "El numero mayor es:" << mayor << endl;
        cout << "El numero menor es:" << menor << endl;
        cout << "Cantidad de impares es:" << ci << endl;
        cout << "Cnatidad de pares es:" << cp << endl;
        cout << "El promedio es:" << prom << endl;
        cout << "Desea continuar [s/n]:";
        cin >> op;
    } while (op == 's');
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. ¿Qué error te da el programa? ¿qué números estás usando?

Comment: El código funciona bien, retira la lineal clrscr(); y dale formato al código para que puedas leerlo, la salida es la adecuada, para tu caso solo debes verificar que el número que ingresa el usuario como parte de la lista sea un número impar, este programa acepta cualquier número, te indica el número de números pares e impares, el promedio, el mayor y menor.

Comment: Además por encima del método main agrega el namespace (`using namespace std;`) para los espacios de nombre de C++.
`... #include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
.
.
.
}`

Comment: Te comparto el código con el namespace para que veas como se ejecuta: 
[Código del Ejemplo](https://onlinegdb.com/S1_YzR_KP) solo debes modificar la lógica para que hagas tu deber.

Comment: @Diego-1743 es preferible usar `std::` a `using namespace std;` ... acostumbrarse desde el principio a importar espacios de nombre indiscriminadamente no es precisamente una buena idea

Comment: @Diego-1743 Muchas gracias master, tu código me sirvió y como dices, ya se donde me equivoque